# Elastic Search 7 : Get distinct hits for a specific field

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I have an index where the _source contains this kind of fields :

```
createDate : date,
fileName: string,
status : string,
taskName: string,
taskType : string
...
```

I would like to know if it's possible to get one hit (any hit would do) for each distinct taskName.

By using aggregations on the taskName, i can get all distinct taskName values, but I lose the information about the taskType.

I would need a list of distinct taskName with their according taskType.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To include the value of `taskType`, you need to use [top_hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

Try out the below query

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "companies": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "taskName"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "top_ids": {
          "top_hits": {
            "_source": {
              "includes": [
                "taskType"
              ]
            },
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```